# Change color of canvas with Kivy while running

Tags: python, kivy

I would like to change the color of my canvas while running.

The color of the canvas should be:

- red if `len(inputtext)%3 == 0`
- green if `len(inputtext)%3 == 1`
- blue if `len(inputtext)%3 == 2`

I don’t know how to write the `color()` method in the code below:

```
kv ="""
RootWidget:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    TextInput:
        id: my_id
        text: 'text'
        on_text: root.color()

    Label:
        id: my_Label
        text: ' '
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: (1., 1., 0.)
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
"""

import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def color(self):
        pass  # <-- here

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the of your question to make it easier to find as well the code formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution :) Just add an attribute which defines the color to the label (in the kv). Then in the `color`-method just set this attribute accordingly.

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout



kv = """
RootWidget:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    TextInput:
        id: my_id
        text: 'text'
        on_text: root.color(self.text)

    Label:
        id: my_Label
        col: (1., 1., 0.)
        text: ' '
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: self.col
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
"""

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def color(self, inputtext):
        if len(inputtext)%3 == 0:
            col = (1,0,0)
        elif len(inputtext)%3 == 1:
            col = (0,1,0)
        else:
            col = (0,0,1)
        self.ids.my_Label.col = col

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```